# Is $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}, f(x)=x^2$ injective? Surjective?

Tags: proof-verification, self-learning

I would say no:

$\text{Suppose } f(a)=f(b) \text{ then } a^2=b^2 \implies \pm a = \pm b \implies -a=b$.

Or simply by counterexample:

$f(-1)=f(1)$

Further, I would say it does not map $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$ because it is always positive.

Comment: On your "Suppose..." line is the $\rightarrow$ supposed to mean implies? Because $\pm a = \pm b$ does not imply $-a = b$.

Comment: It does. How so?

Comment: Stick to your counter-example, that's all you need to show it's not injective.

Comment: @crash I find this confusing since when we take the root we leave open the option for each variable to be either sign. Why would this not imply all permutations?

Comment: I was simply confirming the point made by @James. Your implication is invalid there. I think you are overcomplicating this problem. If you needed to prove a function was injective or surjective, then that would be one thing. But to prove a function is **not** simply requires you to find **one** counterexample for either scenario. So to prove $f(x)$ is not injective, it suffices that $f(-1)=f(1)$. To prove $f(x)$ is not surjective, it suffices to explain that $-1$ is not mapped to by any element in $\mathbb{Z}$ when $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @crash I'm just curious at this point.

Comment: I believe crash is worrying about notation, in particular, what precisely does $\pm a = \pm b$ mean. A clearer thing to write would be "$\pm a = b$" or "$a = b$ or $a = -b$". Anyway, my note was a logical one, not one about notation. It does not follow from $a^2 = b^2$ that $-a = b$, it does follow that either $a=b$ or $-a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

**Not injective (example):**
$$
f(-3)=(-3)^2=(3)^2=f(3);\qquad -3\neq 3
$$
**Not surjective (more explicit description):** To be surjective, every element in the codomain must be mapped to by some element in the domain. This is clearly not the case when $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2$ because none of the negative numbers in the codomain are being mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample $f(-1)=f(1)$ suffices to show $f$ is not injective and your argument for non-surjectivity is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me. Note also that $f$ can't be surjective, since there are elements of $Z$ which are not perfect squares, and so even if you consider $f:Z^+ \rightarrow Z^+,$ $f$is still not surjective, since, for example, there is no element in $Z^+$ who's square is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You are entirely correct. Your counterexample shows that $f$ is not injective, and you have provided valid reasoning that $f$ is not surjectiv.

If you would like some more insight, you can consider the none-negative integers: $Z^{*}$

For example, where $f(x) = x^{2}$ , if we define $f:Z^{*} \rightarrow Z$ it is injective.